# How do I add child view controllers to a tabbed view controller while keeping the tab bar?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2, developing for iOS 10.

I've got a storyboard that looks like this.

The left view controller is one of three child view controllers part of a tab view controller.  The right view controller is a view controller that reveals when "Continue" is clicked.

[image]

However, when clicked, the right view controller takes up the whole view and the tab bar at the bottom disappears.  There is a "Back" button at the top which is good and I would like to keep that but how do I get the tab bar back?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not reproducible based on what you've said. On the contrary, when I set up a storyboard Tab Bar Controller -> Nav Controller -> VC1 -> (push) -> VC2, the tab bar is still there when I go to VC2. I can only conclude that there's some misconfiguration in your storyboard that you have not described accurately.

[image]

Comment: Hi matt, you originally had a comment to my post which I will copy here: "in full disclosure, my full storyboard is: nav controller -> VC (acts as a Terms & Conditions agreement page) -> tab bar controller (three child VCs) -> VC1 (with the continue button) (push) -> VC2. It is the VC2 that is no longer showing the tab bar."

Comment: That is an unsupported configuration. Don't try to put a tab bar controller _inside_ a nav controller. You need to come up with another interface.

Comment: Ah I see.  Okay, how would you recommend setting up the storyboard if I would like there to be a Terms and Conditions page that the user must acknowledge before using the app?  I want there to be that page and once they acknowledge, then they go to the Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: "if I would like there to be a Terms and Conditions page that the user must acknowledge before using the app" But that is one of the most common questions already answered on SO. _Lots_ of suggestions are here for how to do a one-time login or acknowledgment page. I'm happy to talk about how I personally solve the problem, but not in a comment on a totally different question.